# Semi-transparent (blurry like VisualEffectView) of the view behind the current view

Tags: swiftui

In SwiftUI the view behind the tab bar in a TabView will shine through as if the backside of the tab bar was frosted glass. Apple uses this look all over the place in their own apps. But how do I add it to a view in SwiftUI?

Here's an example from the Podcasts app. The tab bar has the frosted glass effect. And so does the overlay mini player on top of the tab bar. Any tab bar in a TabView in will have this look by default, but not an associated overlay (the  mini player in this case).

[image]

Answer (score 76, accepted):

## The Apple way

Investigating on the view hierarchy shows that Apple is using `UIKit` and `UIVisualEffectView`for this reason. You can define a `VisualEffectView` with just 5 lines of code:

```
struct VisualEffectView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var effect: UIVisualEffect?
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) -> UIVisualEffectView { UIVisualEffectView() }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIVisualEffectView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Self>) { uiView.effect = effect }
}
```

Usage Example:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("BG")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            
            VisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .dark))
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                
            Text("Hello \nVisual Effect View")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.black)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Visual Effect View]

---

## The Native SwiftUI way:

You can add `.blur()` modifier on anything you need to be blurry like:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image("BG")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .blur(radius: 20) // <- this is the important modifier. The rest is just for demo
                
            Text("Hello \nSwiftUI Blur Effect")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.black)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: SwiftUI Code]
<sub>Note the top and bottom of the view</sub>

**Note that** you can `Group` multiple views and blur them together.

---

## iOS 15 - Apple Material

You can use iOS predefined materials with one line code:

```
.background(.ultraThinMaterial)
```

[image: Demo]

Comment: Am I right in understanding that `VisualEffectView` blurs the layer underneath, whereas as `blur(radius:opacity:)` just blurs the view that it's applied to? Is there a way to use `blur(radius:opacity:)` to blur the layer underneath?

Comment: I think `VisualEffectView`'s mission is the thing you need and using it inside SwiftUI environment is completely reasonable. @EdwardBrey

Comment: Correct answer. If you do not run live preview, the first approach is not visible. To make it affect , you have to run your app or run live preview.