# SwiftUI contextMenu on material background darkens the content when activated

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm using [material background in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/material/) (introduced with iOS 15). When applied to a view that also has a [contextMenu](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/contextmenu(menuitems:)) modifier when the context menu is shown it darkens the whole content. To make sure it's not related to my project I created an example project and it has the same issue.

Code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(.systemBlue).ignoresSafeArea()
            Text("Press for Context Menu")
                .padding()
                .background(.regularMaterial)
                .contextMenu {
                    Button("Option 1", action: {})
                    Button("Option 2", action: {})
                    Button("Option 3", action: {})
                }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
//            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

Here is the result:
[image: activated context menu darkens the content when material background is used]

Interestingly it works correctly in dark mode:
[image: activated context menu works as expected in dark mode when material background is used]

Answer (score 2):

The order of modifiers matters. To avoid this darkening, simply swap the modifiers, so that the `.contextMenu` is applied before the `.background`:

```
                Text("Press for Context Menu")
                    .padding()
                    .contextMenu {
                        Button("Option 1", action: {})
                        Button("Option 2", action: {})
                        Button("Option 3", action: {})
                    }
                    .background(.regularMaterial)
```

It should look like this:

[image: context menu with material]

Comment: …We've got a race condition here! :P

Answer (score 1):

Add the background with the material **after** the contextMenu modifier. You're still gonna get a weird appearance when opening the contextual menu though, cause another material is applied on top of it.

Comment: Thanks! It's not ideal, but better than using custom VisualEffectView via UIViewRepresentable from https://stackoverflow.com/a/59111191/1659311 which I tried after posting the original question. This is how it looks now: https://imgur.com/a/5Fm7GaO

Comment: Can't you otherwise sort of *mimic* the appearance of the `regularMaterial` applying some view modifiers to the `Text`? I've also noticed that the blur from the contextual menu might slightly change if the `Text` has `fixedSize` applied to it.

Comment: It looks like it's an Apple issue - I'll report it. The workaround is good enough for now.