# Shape with a material foregroundStyle darkens when contextMenu is triggered

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Consider the following simplified snippet

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      Image("Image")
        .resizable()
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
      
      VStack {
        container
        container
        container
        container
        container
        container
      }
    }
  }
  
  var container: some View {
    Rectangle()
      .frame(height: 100)
      .padding(.horizontal)
      .foregroundStyle(.ultraThinMaterial)
      .contextMenu {
        Button {
          print("Hello world")
        } label: {
          Label("Hello world", systemImage: "hand.wave")
        }
      }
  }
}
```

which results in the following layout

[image: layout]

When the contextMenu is triggered, the `Rectangle` turns pitch black
[image: bug example 1]

[image: bug example 2]

As stated in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69959468/swiftui-contextmenu-on-material-background-darkens-the-content-when-activated), the order of the modifier matters. Moving the foregroundStyle below the contextMenu ended up with the same result. I've tried using a Text with a `background` set to a material instead but that reduces the clickable area to the text instead of the larger shape behind it. Is there any way to fix this or is it a SwiftUI bug?