# how to make a apple wallet card background color in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

What do I want to make:
making apple wallet card by below descriptions in SwiftUI:

> The colors of the Apple Card shift with every single transaction you
> make, at the beginning it’s white The next color changes to  whatever
> your first purchase happens to be. Say, for instance you buy food for
> dinner and Since the Food & Drink category of purchases in Apple Card
> are orange-coded, you'll see an orange color bloom over the Apple
> Card. Your second purchase  is  movie thicket."Entertainment" is
> pink-coded in the Apple Card, so the moment you make that purchase, a
> blot of pink will also appear. The size of the blot of pink versus the
> blot of orange will depend on how much money you spent on those
> purchases.

[image]

what have I done so far (I have difficulties with the background color):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let fourColorsGradient = Gradient(colors: [Color.blue, Color.pink, Color.yellow, Color.green])
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                AngularGradient(gradient:  fourColorsGradient , center: .center, startAngle: .degrees(0), endAngle: .degrees(360)).cornerRadius(30)
                    .blur(radius: 1)
                
                
            }
            .frame(width: 340, height: 210)
        }
    }
}
```

The thing that I found is that apple don't use gradient for this situation.

Comment: That's **not** an `AngularGradient`

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini Can you be more specific?

Comment: My answer here goes over some options: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/708855 I would probably stick to the recommendation of solving this with some shapes and a blur, but if you really want to go detailed, you can go for a Gradient Mesh implementation like this one: https://movingparts.io/gradient-meshes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **not** an `AngularGradient`. It is a multi-point gradient, and I think Apple implemented that with metal in the wallet app. But you can mimic the effect pretty close by merging multiple gradient colors over each other and a blur layer on top of everything.

something like this:

[image: Demo]

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {    
    let startRadius: CGFloat = 0
    let endRadius: CGFloat = 200

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RadialGradient(
                colors: [.blue, .blue.opacity(0)],
                center: .bottomLeading,
                startRadius: startRadius,
                endRadius: endRadius
            )
            RadialGradient(
                colors: [.red, .red.opacity(0)],
                center: .topTrailing,
                startRadius: startRadius,
                endRadius: endRadius
            )
            RadialGradient(
                colors: [.yellow, .yellow.opacity(0)],
                center: .topLeading,
                startRadius: startRadius,
                endRadius: endRadius
            )
            
            VisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .regular))
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}
```

You can use `.blur` modifier but here is **[how to create VisualEffectView in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59111191/5623035)**